# How to add shortcut of any folder application to Windows right click permanently?

Tags: windows-xp, context-menu

Is there any other lightweight portable utility than in "[Adding items to a files right click menu in Windows Explorer](https://superuser.com/questions/55731/adding-items-to-a-files-right-click-menu-in-windows-explorer)"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know if this is what you want, but have a look at [this Lifehacker post](http://lifehacker.com/5457243/jdcontextmenu-enhances-windows-right-click-menu):

[image: Screenshot]

> Windows: JDContextMenu is a small
>   application that adds a variety of
>   useful shortcuts to the right-click
>   context menu in Windows.
>
> None of the shortcuts are things you
>   couldn't do within Windows with a few
>   extra clicks or with a small 3rd-party
>   app, but JDContextMenu bundles them
>   together into a small menu with
>   one-click ease. You can copy the full
>   filename to the clipboard, alter the
>   time and date stamp of a file, run an
>   MD5 checksum to verify file integrity,
>   and create new folders—the new folder
>   tool allows you to create a variable
>   number of numbered folders in a
>   series.
>
> JDContextMenu is freeware, Windows
>   only.

Comment: where is the link of post?

Comment: Here it is: http://lifehacker.com/5457243/jdcontextmenu-enhances-windows-right-click-menu

Answer (score 0):

I've made [a script for this purpose named "shellex.bat"](http://eadmaster.altervista.org/pub/index.php?page=cliapps#reassoc)

Usage:

```
shellex FTYPE NAME COMMAND [ICON_PATH]
```

Icons are supported in Windows >=7 only.

With this script you can collect all the shell extensions you like in a batch file and easily move them from one box to another.